# pandas: Filter a whole group out based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I've created the following MWE

```
data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom' , 'Tom', 'Tom', 'Tom'], 'Article': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 'Weekday' : [1,2,3,2,3,1,2,3, 1, 2], 'Value': [1,40,3,91,10,6,9,10, 20, 10]}  

df_test = pd.DataFrame(data)

        Name    Article Weekday Value
    0   Tom        A    1       1
    1   Tom        A    2      40
    2   Tom        A    3       3
    3   Tom        B    2      91
    4   Tom        B    3      10
    5   Tom        A    1       6
    6   Tom        A    2       9
    7   Tom        A    3      10
    8   Tom        B    1      20
    9   Tom        B    2      10
```

where a group consists of Name-Article pairs. I want to filter all groups out that dont have at least 2 counts in values for all three existing weekdays. So there should be only groups having three weekdays (1,2,3) and with at least two counts. If a Name-Article has only two weekdays with at least two counts it should be filtered out as well.

The expected output should look like this

```
        Name    Article Weekday Value
    0   Tom        A    1       1
    1   Tom        A    2      40
    2   Tom        A    3       3
    5   Tom        A    1       6
    6   Tom        A    2       9
    7   Tom        A    3      10
```

Comment: What does means `at least two counts` ?

Comment: 2 entries for the Name-Article-Weekday combinations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to ensure at least 2 counts per `Name`/`Article` **per `Weekday`**, you can compute a [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) to count the combinations of `Name`/`Article` and `Weekday`.

Then you can use any filter you want, here we keep the `Name`/`Article` combinations that have [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) at least 2 values:

```
counts = pd.crosstab([df_test['Name'], df_test['Article']], df_test['Weekday'])
keep = counts[counts.ge(2).all(axis=1)]

out = df_test.set_index(['Name', 'Article']).loc[keep.index].reset_index()

# or
# out = df_test.merge(keep[[]].reset_index())
```

To count not `all` days but only a given number (e.g. ≥3), use:

```
keep = counts[counts.ge(2).sum(axis=1).ge(3)]
```

Output:

```
  Name Article  Weekday  Value
0  Tom       A        1      1
1  Tom       A        2     40
2  Tom       A        3      3
3  Tom       A        1      6
4  Tom       A        2      9
5  Tom       A        3     10
```

Intermediate `counts`:

```
Weekday       1  2  3
Name Article         
Tom  A        2  2  2  # all 3 have ≥ 2, we keep
     B        1  2  1  # not all ≥ 2, discard
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filtering:

```
s = df_test.groupby(['Name','Article','Weekday']).size()
m = s.ge(2).groupby(level=[0,1]).sum().ge(3)
df = df_test[df_test.set_index(['Name', 'Article']).index.isin(m.index[m])]
print (df)
  Name Article  Weekday  Value
0  Tom       A        1      1
1  Tom       A        2     40
2  Tom       A        3      3
5  Tom       A        1      6
6  Tom       A        2      9
7  Tom       A        3     10
```

How it working:

```
#get counts per Name/Article/Weekday
print (df_test.groupby(['Name','Article','Weekday']).size())
Name  Article  Weekday
Tom   A        1          2
               2          2
               3          2
      B        1          1
               2          2
               3          1
dtype: int64

#test if greater or equal like 2
print (s.ge(2))
Tom   A        1           True
               2           True
               3           True
      B        1          False
               2           True
               3          False
dtype: bool
```

---

```
#count Trues per Name/Article
print (s.ge(2).groupby(level=[0,1]).sum())
Tom   A          3
      B          1
dtype: int64

#test if counts greater/ equal like 3
print (s.ge(2).groupby(level=[0,1]).sum().ge(3))
Tom   A           True
      B          False
      
#filter Name/Article
print (m.index[m])
MultiIndex([('Tom', 'A')],
           names=['Name', 'Article'])

#filter combinaton from original DataFrame Name/Article
print (df_test.set_index(['Name', 'Article']).index.isin(m.index[m]))
[ True  True  True False False  True  True  True False False]
```

Similar solution if need test if all NAme/Article has 2 or more counts with [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html):

```
s = df_test.groupby(['Name','Article','Weekday']).size()
m = s.ge(2).groupby(level=[0,1]).all()

df1 = df_test[df_test.set_index(['Name', 'Article']).index.isin(m.index[m])]
print (df1)
  Name Article  Weekday  Value
0  Tom       A        1      1
1  Tom       A        2     40
2  Tom       A        3      3
5  Tom       A        1      6
6  Tom       A        2      9
7  Tom       A        3     10
```